# Error [405] Method Not Allowed in Bot Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, chatbot

I'm currently following the 'Build a chat bot with the Azure Bot Service' course, when I begin to dialogue with the bot in 'Bot Framework Emulator', the error "Error [405] Method Not Allowed " appears in Visual Studio Code.
I dont't understand from where this problem comes from.
After consulting some documentation, it's maybe a problem of version and update.

The complete error is :

```js
Error: GET to 'http://localhost:61618/v3/botstate/emulator/conversations/d4ca28c0-6e7c-11ea-986d-b7f1d80fdacd%7Clivechat/users/91c77760-1db3-40b7-a581-badc276ad5e2' failed: [405] Method Not Allowed
    at Request._callback (c:\Users\benji\Downloads\factbot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\ChatConnector.js:545:46)
    at Request.self.callback (c:\Users\benji\Downloads\factbot\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (c:\Users\benji\Downloads\factbot\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (c:\Users\benji\Downloads\factbot\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1201:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message specifies "Method Not Allowed".
You're most likely using a GET verb when you should use a POST verb.